# Unidentified assertion in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, assertions

In my iOS App I'm seeing in the Console window of Xcode when I run on the iOS 9.2 Simulator the following message:

```
(assertion failed: 15C50 13C75: assertiond + 13207 [792516D1-991E-36EE-8454-16F8220758D6]: 0x1)
```

It's not a major problem, but since it hinders proper debug message reading, I was trying to investigate which code was throwing the assertion.

### That's what I tried so far:

#### Set a `NSAssertionHandler` breakpoint.

1. Go to the XCode 7 breakpoint navigator.
2. Click the + button and choose "Add Symbolic Breakpoint"
3. Set Symbol: to "-[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]"
4. Click "Done"

But it did not stop in any place and it prints the message.

#### Set a breakpoint for any exception.

1. Go to the breakpoint navigator.
2. Click the + button and choose "Add Exception Breakpoint"
3. Set Exception: to "Objective-C"
4. Set Break: to "On Throw"
5. Click "Done"

Also don't stop in any place and print the message.

I have also tried to set symbolic breakpoints for `NSAssert` and `assert`

How can I identify which code is triggering this assertion?

### Additional Data

It seems that the code below throw this exception

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:reloadPaths 
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```